# What is the max users you can have access a localhost web app?

Tags: localhost

I have a Dash application that is being utilized internally without the need or desire for public access. Currently, the host has been opened up so that anyone on the network can access the application however I am thinking long term with 100+ users this might be an issue.

Does anyone know how many users a localhost can handle before it is too much?

Comment: There's no difference between running a website on a localhost server versus on a cloud server; it all depends on how much traffic the individual machine can handle.

Comment: Thank you. This was my assumption and research but just wanted to see if there was any known limitations I might not be seeing.